# How can I access methods inside a class from outside of class

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchbase

I have a couple questions regarding Class files. I have the below Class

```
class CouchController {
constructor(couchbase, config) {
    // You may either pass couchbase and config as params, or import directly into the controller
    this.cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(config.cluster);
    this.cluster.authenticate(config.userid, config.password);
    this.bucket = cluster.openBucket(config.bucket);
    this.N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;
  }

        doSomeQuery(queryString, callback) {
              this.bucket.manager().createPrimaryIndex(function() {            
              this.bucket.query(
                this.N1qlQuery.fromString("SELECT * FROM bucketname WHERE $1 in interests LIMIT 1"),
                [queryString],
                callback(err, result)
              )     
            });
          }
  }
```

my problem is how can I go and access the doSomeQuery function from outside the class file? Inside there is no issue accessing the function but I need to be able to call it from outside.
I tried something like this

```
const CouchController = require("../controllers/CouchController")(couchbase, config)
let newTest = new CouchController
```

doing so newTest never exposes the doSomeQuery method.

Also what are the limitations of a method ? Can it only be a simple one or can it be async and use promises etc ?

Comment: `newTest.doSomeQuery()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 main things that you should consider with the following problem.

1. Export it properly first. I'm not sure if you meant to leave this out, but it's important to export the class for use outside as a `require`. Here is the [NodeJS exports documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/modules.html#modules_exports) if you wish for the technical details.

```
// common module default export
module.exports = class CouchController {
  constructor(couchbase, config) {
    // You may either pass couchbase and config as params, or import directly into the controller
    this.cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(config.cluster);
    this.cluster.authenticate(config.userid, config.password);
    this.bucket = cluster.openBucket(config.bucket);
    this.N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;
  }

        doSomeQuery(queryString, callback) {
              this.bucket.manager().createPrimaryIndex(function() {            
              this.bucket.query(
                this.N1qlQuery.fromString("SELECT * FROM bucketname WHERE $1 in interests LIMIT 1"),
                [queryString],
                callback(err, result)
              )     
            });
          }
  }
```

2. The class initialization is slightly incorrect. You can see the docs on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). You can change your require and initialization to...

```
const CouchController = require('../controllers/CouchController');
const newTest = new CouchController(couchbase, config);

// now you can access the function :)
newTest.doSomeQuery("query it up", () => {
// here is your callback
})
```

*If you were using ES6 modules or typescript you could export something like...*

```
export default class CouchController {
  // ...
}
```

*... and import something like...*

```
import CouchController from '../controllers/CouchController';

const newTest = new CouchController(couchbase, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the class after importing it

Change the following

```
const CouchController = require("../controllers/CouchController")(couchbase, config)
let newTest = new CouchController
```

to

```
const CouchController = require("../controllers/CouchController")
let newTest = new CouchController(couchbase, config)
```

Also you need to export your class like this

`export default class CouchController {`

and then access method like this

`newTest.doSomeQuery(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after some forth and back, part of my problem was the fact that for some reason visual studio code did not show me the method which threw me off. Manually typing made it ultimately avail.

Here is my Class and i actually moved the config and couchbase itself into the class file so no need to pass it anymore.

```
const couchbase = require("couchbase")
const config = require("../config/config")

 class CouchController {
    constructor() {
        // You may either pass couchbase and config as params, or import directly into the controller
        this.cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(config.cluster);
        this.cluster.authenticate(config.userid, config.password);
        this.bucket = this.cluster.openBucket(config.bucket);
        this.N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;
      }



            getDoc2(docID){
                return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                  this.bucket.get(docID ,(err, result)=>{
                    if(err) return reject(err);
                    return resolve({docID,result});
                  });
                });
              }




      }

     module.exports = CouchController
```

And here is how i call my Class now and connect to the backend to fetch my data.

```
const CouchController = require("./controllers/CouchController")
let newTest = new CouchController


const test= async()=>{
    let { docID, result } = await newTest.getDoc2("grid_info::20b05192-79e9-4e9d-94c9-91a4fc0a2765")

    console.log(docID)
    console.log(result)
}
```